# Multiply block matrices with uneven blocks

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a way to multiply matrices which are divided into blocks of the form

\begin{bmatrix}
    A&B
\end{bmatrix}

For some $n\times n $ matrix A and $n \times 1$ matrix B with its transpose from the left? Without having to multiply every entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean $\begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix}$.

Then multiplication can be done using block matrices

$\begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} A^T \\ B^T \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} A^TA & A^TB  \\ B^TA & B^TB\end{bmatrix} $

Operation is possible if dimensions of block matrices are appropriate for multiplication operation. In this case they are appropriate:

$ A^TA:   \ \ $ $n \times n , n \times n$ result $n \times n  $

$ A^TB:   \ \ $ $n \times n , n \times 1$ result $n \times 1  $

$ B^TA:   \ \ $ $1 \times n , n \times n$ result $1 \times n  $

$ B^TB:   \ \ $ $1 \times n , n \times 1$ result $1 \times 1  $.